# how to use HttpClient in WindowsPhone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, httpclient

Hey everyone i have a big problem with this thing. i'm trying to use HttpClient method in my new project. i try this code:

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var request = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com/",                     UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        var txt = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        MessageBox.Show(txt.Result);
```

i think it is true code because i wrote it in Console app and it works fine. Then i opened a new WindowsPhone 8 project and write this code.And code doesn't work, it returns Null. Sometimes it works but generally not. i thought my Visual Studio wasnt work good and i deleted it and re-install it, and nothing had been changed. what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com/",                     UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var txt = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        MessageBox.Show(txt.Result);
```

make the breakpoint in the line `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` to make sure response httpcode is 200 every time.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling `Result`. Try this instead:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var request = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
var txt = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MessageBox.Show(txt);
```

Comment: Do you mean `request` or `txt`?

Comment: Do you have the `Microsoft.Net.Http` NuGet package installed?

Comment: Check for error code from the `request`, like by calling `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` method on it.

Comment: @StephenCleary yes i have.

Comment: @Haspemulator it trows a HttpRequestException

Comment: @KaanYurdakök that's great! It means, your http request is not working for some reason. Check `Message` property of the thrown exception to find out what's exactly wrong.

Comment: @Haspemulator isn't it funny ,it says '404- Not found' ?

Comment: Looks like you've been banned on Google. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576501/how-to-send-post-request-with-parameters-asynchronously-in-windows-phone-8

checkout answer in above link.