# Windows phone: what to do with webresponse object?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a simple rss feed reader. I got this webresponse object but how to extract text,links from this?

> WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);

Also,can anyone tell me what is the underlying framework behind all the working of windows phone 8.Is it known as Silverlight?I want to know it so that I can make relevant Google searches and don't bother you people time and again?

Comment: You can use HttpClient instead. An example is available at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408890/how-to-use-httpclient-in-windowsphone-8

Comment: If Windows Phone 8 doesn't get you any good results, I think you could search for winrt, windows 8, or windows store apps, as well as silverlight of course.

Comment: Will it let me download the Images also?

Comment: Well yeah, just use another "GetXXXAsync" method. They're all documented, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx

Comment: After some Googling,I got to know that it is not supported on Windows phone platform.Right?

Comment: HttpClient is supported on windows phone 8 but you have to download using NuGet the portable library system.net.http released by microsoft, the httpClient simplify a lot the procedure for http request

Comment: Looks for **Portable HttpClient**. WP8 is based on the core of WinRT (ie. Windows 8). C# and XAML are the main technologies, and the 'Silverlight' label doesn't apply anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with it. You will need to get the Stream and then from there  can turn it into a string (or other primitive type), just Json.Net to convert from json to an object, or you can use the stream to create an image.

```
using (var response = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        // need a string?
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Need to convert from json?
        MyObject obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(result);

    }
}
```